# FIN-ACK packet is sent from the server, but client sends HTTP request before client sends FIN-ACK packet

Tags: networking, tcp, wireshark, tcpdump

As expected behavior, when server sends FIN-ACK packet, client should also send FIN-ACK packet and the connection is terminated. But for some of my cases, when server sends FIN-ACK packet, immediately new http request is going from the client, before FIN-ACK is sent back from client. This is causing connection reset packet. What is the reason behind this and how to solve this issue.

Comment: "_As expected behavior, when server sends FIN-ACK packet, client should also send FIN-ACK packet and the connection is terminated._" That is simply not true. FIN only means the sender of the FIN will no longer send data, but it is obligated to remain open to receive data until the other side is also done sending data.

Answer (score 1):

> ... when server sends FIN-ACK packet, client should also send FIN-ACK packet ...

While common this is not actually required. FIN from a server signals only that the server will not send any more data - but it still might receive data. Similar a FIN from the client signals that the client will not send any more data - but it might also still receive data. Only when both sides have send a FIN and got the matching ACK, then it is clear that no more data will be send in both direction and thus the connection is closed.

> ...  when server sends FIN-ACK packet, immediately new request is going from the client, before FIN-ACK is sent back from client.

There is no "request" at the TCP level. Request and response have only a meaning at the application level for some application protocols. It is unclear what application protocol is spoken here.

> What is the reason behind this and how to solve this issue.

As said above, FIN from the server only means that the server will not send any more data. But it might still receive data. Nothing here forbids the client to send more data. There is no issue to solve here.

Comment: Actually a http request is going after FIN-ACK from server, which is causing connection reset.

Comment: @ElsonD'Sa: With HTTP persistent connection such race condition is possible. The server can close the connection at any time after the response was sent and before a new request was received.

Comment: connection reset flag is sent from server after the get request. The response is not obtained for the given request. How to handle this issue sir

Comment: @ElsonD'Sa: see [RFC 7230 section 6.31 "Retrying Requests"](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-6.3.1)